# null pointer in listview

Tags: java, android, listview

i have a listview which will retrieve detail and date from database. now im going add one textfield inside the listview. The textfield is for me to compare the date from database and count the remain day. First, i try to get the current the date to test whether can show the date in the listview or nt and  i fail to show it.

```
           package my.com.chyi.schedulev2;

         import android.app.Activity;
         import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Intent;
          import android.database.Cursor;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.View;
          import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
           import android.widget.AdapterView;
              import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
             import android.widget.Button;
           import android.widget.ListView;
           import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
          import java.util.Calendar;

          import my.com.chyi.schedulev2.SQLController;

          /**
        * Created by chyi1_000 on 3/19/2015.
          */
   public class assigmentActivity extends Activity {

Button addass_bt;
ListView lv;
SQLController dbcon;
TextView assID_tv,assName_tv,assAtime_tv,assRemain;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assign);

    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    dbcon.open();
    //assign module
    addass_bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addAss_bt_id);
    lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.assList_id);

    //assig module
    addass_bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent add_ass = new Intent(assigmentActivity.this,Add_Assignment.class);
            startActivity(add_ass);
        }
    });

    //assig module
    Cursor cursor = dbcon.readDataA();
    //calculate days different
  // list -> loop
    // each row different days


    String[] fromA = new String[] { DBhelper.ASSIGNMENT_ID,DBhelper.ASSIGNMENT_NAME,DBhelper.ASSIGNMENT_mTime, };
    int[] toA = new int[] { R.id.assigment_id, R.id.assigment_name, R.id.assigment_ATime};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapterA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
           assigmentActivity.this, R.layout.view_assignment_entry, cursor, fromA, toA);
    adapterA.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapterA);

    // assig module
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            assID_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assigment_id);
            assName_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assigment_name);
            assAtime_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.assigment_ATime);


            Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat dfd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String formattedDateD = dfd.format(d.getTime().toString());
            String test = formattedDateD;
            String assID_val = assID_tv.getText().toString();
            String assName_val = assName_tv.getText().toString();
            String assATime_val =  assAtime_tv .getText().toString();

            Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Modify_assignment.class);
            modify_intent.putExtra("assName", assName_val);
            modify_intent.putExtra("assID", assID_val);
            modify_intent.putExtra("assAtime",assATime_val);
            startActivity(modify_intent);
        }
    });

  TextView babu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assigment_remain);
   Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat dfd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDateD = dfd.format(d.getTime().toString());
    babu.setText(formattedDateD);
 }
```

}

i get error at  java.lang.NullPointerException at bubu.setText(formattedDateD);
may i know wht is the problem?thank for the help. my listview will auto get all the data from my SQLController, so i cannot add extra textfield in the listview.

```
      public Cursor readDataA(){
         String[] allcolumnsA = new String[] {                                  DBhelper.ASSIGNMENT_ID,DBhelper.ASSIGNMENT_NAME,DBhelper.ASSIGNMENT_mTime};
    Cursor e = database.query(DBhelper.TABLE_ASSIGNMENT, allcolumnsA,null, null, null, null, null);
    if (e != null ) {
        e.moveToFirst();

    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: does d.getTime() return something?

Comment: does the format returns something. Just change the format to `dd-MMM-yyyy`

Comment: the d.getTime() is for get the current date from calendar, i tried this code at new project and its work, bt at this project fail

Comment: Is this line `TextView babu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assigment_remain)` returning a `null` `View`? Can you debug it?

Comment: I believe the line TextView babu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assigment_remain); is returning Null.

Comment: Your textView `babu` is inside the listView?

Comment: ya..i plan put textview babu into the listview

Answer (score 0):

Try with "yyyy-MM-dd" as the pattern .

Answer (score 0):

Add one 'M' to your date format

Answer (score 0):

```
String formattedDateD = dfd.format(d.getTime()).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

> i get error at java.lang.NullPointerException at bubu.setText(formattedDateD);

This would suggest that `bubu` (or `babu` as you have it in your code) is null.

I would take a look at this line:

```
TextView babu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assigment_remain);
```

This is probably not finding the view and hence returning null.

Your code needs to cope with that case and you also need to track down why you have the wrong id for your view.